# DirectShow - IEnumMediaTypes::Next fails in a certain scenario

Tags: .net, graph, filter, directshow

We have a DLL that builds a Directshow graph for streaming live video. I am now building a small .NET application that uses this DLL, and encountering a strange problem. At the point where the graph is being built and the various filter pins connected to each other, the call to IEnumMediaTypes::Next fails when trying to find the decoder filter's output media types. This is strange for 2 reasons - first, this DLL has been used many a time in other apps we have built, and second - if I run the the DLL's project in Debug (VS2010) using the main application as the running target, everything works just fine.

Any ideas as to where I need to look for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> ... the call to IEnumMediaTypes::Next **fails** when trying...

This is the part you need to elaborate. Returns error code - which exactly? Crashes with memory access violation? What is the graph topology at that time. What is call stack.